# PHP Mink when i change session, the data that used in foreach changes

Tags: php, foreach, mink

For example if i create a array and run foreach on it

```
<?php

     $array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];

      foreach($array as $number){

        echo $number."<br>";

        $array = ['a','b','c','d'];

      }

 ?>
```

result :

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

and change set the array after echo out the numbers , array doesn't change
or even if I add new item on array it will not change that result , I mean array will not change in foreach

```
 foreach ....
 echo $number."<br>";
 $array[]='x';
 ...
```

result : same

but when I do something like that
$selected_category setted to a link;

```
$session = Helpers::mink($selected_category);

            $page = $session->getPage();

            $as =  $page->find('css', 'div#seasons-list')->findAll('css','a');

            $items = [];
            foreach ($as as $value) {

                $link = $value->getAttribute('href');



                $session->visit($link);

                $page = $session->getPage();

                $episodes = $page->find('css','div#category-posts')->findAll('css','article.grid-box');


                foreach ($episodes as $episode) {

                /* line 97 */       $link = $episode->find('css','a')->getAttribute('href');    

                    /* line 98 */   $session->visit($link);

                        $page = $session->getPage();

                        $items[] = $a= $page->findAll('css','span.embed-responsive-item')[0]->find('css','iframe')->getAttribute('src');
}
```

first gets the data that  I expected and when I set new url on session 
on line 98 and when this returns
i get this error
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getAttribute() on null ... line 97

that means $episodes object changed , but why , why it doesn't change on first foreach and it changes in second

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that:

1. on every page reload/refresh the object is lost
   Example: find element > refresh the page / navigate to similar page > do some action on the object element saved earlier in a variable => stale element error from selenium
2. make sure you are using the methods the right way
   Example: `find()` method will return an element object if the element is found **OR** it will return `null` if the element is not found.

The second is your case, you are using `getAttribute` on `null`, you should handle this kind of error (fatal error in this case).

In order to handle it make sure the element is found, search for the element with `find` then check if what returns is `null`, if yes then throw an exception.